# What's the proper way to setup API references during development, when you run the dev API locally?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, npm, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

**BACKGROUND**

I'm setting up a new front-end web projects.  The application I'm working on is also a new Visual Studio ASP.Net Core Web API. All of my UI work is part of the same git repository, but is not included in the Web API solution.

For development, I run the API in Visual Studio so that I can easily start/stop and break on code, and I use `npm` to start and run my UI application from VS Code.

**QUESTION**

Obviously, I need to make API calls within my application.  To do this, I can make calls like:

```
fetch('http://localhost:55555/api/test')
```

The obvious problem is that `http://localhost:55555` is a local address and this will need to obviously be published to servers for dev and staging as well as production.  Instead, I should define some type of environment variable that will replace the hardcoded address with the correct root address, and my code should reference that configuration value

Eventually we are going to setup a CI pipeline for this project, so I need to be sure I'm setting up the types of config settings that will differ from server to server the application is published too. That said, my google searches aren't helping me find the proper way to define web API addresses in environment variables  or configuration files that I can access within my code.

How do I setup an npm/React application so that it can access a config-define API address, that can later be easily changed based off of the environment it's published too?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @SakoBu Yes, I did.

Comment: Also, I'm developing in Windows and these apps will be published to Windows servers, if that matters.

Comment: Here you go: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: @SakoBu I read that, but it didn't work. I think I'm missing a step or somthing.  I added a `process.env` file to my app and added a test variable (`REACT_APP_TEST_NAME=Test App`) I couldn't get it to output.  No errors were being reported either.

Comment: It might be worth noting, in create-react-app, if you have created a `.env` file and tried to add a variable i.e. `REACT_APP_TEST_VAR='test string'`, you need to restart your dev server in order for those variables to be recognized. Then you should be able to log `process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_VAR` and access the string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `config.js` in the `src`... In there do something like this:

```
export const API_BASE_URL =
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:55555/api';
```

And then wherever you need it you can import and use it like so:

```
import { API_BASE_URL } from './config';
```

Something like:

```
 fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/etc...`)
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <div>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</div>; // (if in developement should say development)
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if it says `development`

Comment: Thank you.  I can get the values to load from `config.js` but when I add `process.env`, I can't get it to read values from there.  Any idea?

Comment: Your edit worked, however, the problem seems to be that I can't get my app to read my process.env file. This might have something to do with being in dev?

Comment: Sorry, I never could get this to work with `.env` or `process.env` files.  However, one question I could never figure out is if those files go in the `src` folder or the actual root folder where other files like `README.md` and `package.json` belong.

Comment: @RLH If the 'edit' worked it's working... not sure how else to explain or clarify... To answer your question... The `.env` should be at the root ( same as`README.md` `package.json` etc) The config you can have anywhere as long as the relative path when importing is good (more often than not I put it in the `src`... )